# SQL to get order items from Magento?

Tags: php, mysql, magento, magento-1.9, magento2

I need to get a list of ordered physical items to ship from the database. The list need to consist of name, sku, quantity, price, weight, and dimensions.

How can we fo this without using Magento's own framework components.

The problem is that if a product contains options it appears multiple times in the table by different product types (simple, bundle, configurable, etc.) and different product ids.

```
$items = array();

$sql = (
  "SELECT oi.name, oi.sku, oi.qty_ordered, oi.price, oi.weight
  FROM {$db->prefix}sales_flat_order_item oi
  WHERE oi.order_id = ". (int)$order_entity_id .";"
);

if ($result = $mysqli->query($sql)) {

  while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    $items[] = [
      'name'                   => $row['name'],
      'sku'                    => $row['sku'],
      'quantity'               => (float)$row['qty_ordered'],
      'unit_price'             => (float)$row['price'],
      'unit_weight'            => (float)$row['weight'],
      //'unit_length'            => (float)$row['length'], // Not present?
      //'unit_width'             => (float)$row['width'], // Not present?
      //'unit_height'            => (float)$row['height'], // Not present?
    ];
  }

  $result->close();
}
```

If I pass a filter `AND product_type = 'simple'` to get only the simple products, they do not contain price.

Comment: Hi,
If you look at the SKU in the row of the configurable or bundle product is exactly the same SKU of the simple product related to this row.
If in your catalog there are orders that could have only simples that are not set up by a configurable product then I'm afraid that you should apply some logic.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'm not sure if sku is mandatory or optional in Magento. In most other e-commerce platforms they are optional. If they are grouped by sku I still don't need what fields rule out the other when it comes to price, quantity, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If there is a configurable product which have multiple simple products with same price, then the price will be saved only in the configurable product. So you should not use the 'simple product' filter. 
Try with below query,

```
SELECT orders.increment_id AS increment_id,
       orders.status AS order_status,
       orders.customer_email AS customer_email,
       orders.coupon_code AS coupon_code,
       items.name AS item_name,
       items.item_id AS order_item_id,
       items.sku AS item_sku,
       items.base_price AS item_base_price,
       items.price_incl_tax AS item_price,
       items.qty_ordered AS qty_ordered,
       items.product_id AS product_id,
       items.weight AS Weight
    FROM sales_flat_order_item AS items
    LEFT JOIN sales_flat_order AS orders
    ON items.order_id = orders.entity_id 
  WHERE 
    orders.entity_id = 18229
```

This gives you the details of both Simple and Configurable product and you can filer the contents using conditions (if / else).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT ord_items.name, ord_items.sku, ord_items.qty_ordered, ord_items.weight, ord_items.price
FROM sales_flat_order_item as ord_items
WHERE ord_items.product_type = 'configurable' OR ord_items.product_type = 'bundle';
```

Note that for Magento the SKU is an identifier and in sales_flat tables this the attribute used to link a bundle or configurable products to its simple. The parent product (configurable or bundle) has all the info that you need in your query.

*With this query to are assuming that in this shop you only sell bundle or configurable products.

Comment: That didn't return anything for orders with only simple products.

Comment: Of course, that's what I commented above. The only way to do this without any logic is separate in two queries.
Magento saves the simple product in a "different way" in the table sales_flat_order_item depending if the simple product was bought by a configurable or directly the simple one.